# Python logger - bug with NFS

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I am configuring a python logger with 2 file handlers (1 for all kinds of logs, and 1 for error logs only).

Both file handlers are instances of TimeRotatingFileHandler, with argument `when ='midnight'`, and are pointed to file reside on NFS mounted point
(Code attached)

I'm encountering some weird problems after logging for more than 24 hours straight:

1. The logs are written sometimes to the backup file named `data.log.2020-08-23` (yesterday), and sometimes to the "today" log called `data.log`.
2. The **actual** log of 2020-08-23 exists in a file called `.nfs000000....6c`

(EDIT: I am using the logger from multiple threads as well)

The code I use to create the logger:

```
import logging
from logging import TimeRotatingFileHandler
...
...
fh = TimeRotatingFileHandler('/opt/logs/data.log', when='midnight', backupCount=365)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d %(name)s %(levelname)s; %(message)s %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
fh.setFormatter(formatter)

# Error logger
fh2 = TimeRotatingFileHandler('/opt/logs/error.log', when='midnight', backupCount=365)
fh2.setFormatter(formatter)
fh2.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

logger = logging.getLogger('data')
logger.addHandler(fh)
logger.addHandler(fh2)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

return logger
```

Will appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Comment: Hmm... the logging modules advertises to be thread safe through internal locking, so logging from multiple threads should not be an issue. But you say that you find a file containing *nfs* in its name. Could the file reside on a NFS mount? Locking over NFS is known to be unsafe...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yes, the file reside on an NFS mount indeed - is that what causing the problem? How can I fix this while keeping the NFS mount?

Comment: I would never try to log over nfs. In order to log over the network, I will use a `SyslogHandler` if possible as a last way use a QueueListener, QueueHandler pair to ensure that only one thread tries to access the nfs mount. Only a comment because I am unsure of the robustness nor applicability.

Comment: Thank you. I am using ICP, with a PVC, thus I need the NFS. But I can use other file systems. Which of the following is the best for the purpose of logging?
 *   GCEPersistentDisk
 *   AWSElasticBlockStore
 *   AzureFile
 *   AzureDisk
 *   CSI
 *   FC (Fibre Channel)
 *   FlexVolume
 *   Flocker
 *   NFS
 *   iSCSI
 *   RBD (Ceph Block Device)
 *   CephFS
 *   Cinder (OpenStack block storage)
 *   Glusterfs
 *   VsphereVolume
 *   Quobyte Volumes
 *   HostPath
 *   Portworx Volumes
 *   ScaleIO Volumes
 *   StorageOS

Comment: I am sorry but I am not a specialist of network storage, so I cannot answer. I just remember NFS to be lock unfriendly because I was bitten. If you cannot use a local disk, you should probably try the QueueListener, QueueHandler pair. Anyway, you should edit your question to say that you need to store the logs on a network storage, because I think that it matters.